# Asterisk next to an x-axis label, ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I am creating a bar chart in ggplot2, with every year from 2010-2022 on the x axis.

```r
Year <- c(2010:2022)
```

However, I would like an asterisk by 2022, so I can make a note in the caption saying that the figures for this year are incomplete. I am not sure how to do this. I have tried `Year <- c(2010:2021, "2022*")` but that obviously did not work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to pass a small custom function to the `labels` argument of the scale which using an `ifelse` and `paste0` adds an asterix to the label for year 2022.

Using some fake example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(
  Year = 2010:2022,
  value = seq(13)
)

ggplot(dat, aes(Year, value)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = dat$Year,
    labels = ~ ifelse(.x == 2022, paste0(.x, "*"), .x)
  )
```

[image]